# android getting rid of two warnings

Tags: android, warnings, hashmap

I am learning how to use HashMaps,

my test project is working, but i need to get rid of some warnings,

```
public static void main() {


    Map <String, String>mMap = new HashMap<String, String>(); //crea nuevo HashMap
    mMap.put("llave 1", "la llave uno"); //le mete cosas al hashMap
    mMap.put("llave 2", "la llave dos");
    mMap.put("llave 3", "la llave tres");
    mMap.put("llave 4", "la llave cuatro");

    Iterator iter = mMap.entrySet().iterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
         Map.Entry menEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();

         Log.d("msg", "key:"+menEntry.getKey() +" value:"+menEntry.getValue());
    } } }
```

so on

> Iterator iter = mMap.entrySet().iterator();

i get the warning: `multiple markers at this line` the autocompletition point to `Iterator <E>` what is this, the cast?, Error?, what to put in there?

also same warning in:

> Map.Entry menEntry = (Map.Entry) iter.next();

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are not defining the type at couple of place, that is

```
Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iter = mMap.entrySet().iterator();
```

and

```
 Map.Entry<String, String> menEntry = (Map.Entry<String, String>) iter.next();
```

**Edit**

You can have a look at  Generics in JAVA 1.5, [`here`](http://www.javabeat.net/articles/33-generics-in-java-50-1.html) is a small explanation for that.

Answer (score 1):

This warnings show that you use classes, that will be better to parameterize. use `Iterator <Entry<String, String>>` and `Map.Entry<String, String>`